# grep has different result in terminal command line and bash script

Tags: bash, grep, git

I have a bash script that uses grep to screen out file with certain extensions and under certain directories. The script looks something like follows:

```
generate_exclud_extensions() {
  echo "\"(cpp$"
}

generate_exclude_dirs() {
  echo "|^test)\""
}

command=$(generate_exclud_extensions)$(generate_exclude_dir)
echo $command
git ls-files | grep -vE $command
```

This script was supposed to screen the files with `cpp` extension, AND files under `test` directory. However the result only screened out the first, had the second remained.

Fact 1: `echo $command` outputs `"(cpp$|^test)"`, and running the full command `git ls-files | grep -vE ""(cpp$|^test)""` in terminal, I got the correct result.

Fact 2: Tried using grep twice as follows:

```
git ls-files | grep -vE "cpp$" | grep -vE "^test"
```

same wrong result in bash script but correct in terminal.

I've been searching but didn't have an luck yet. I appreciate it if someone could shed some light on this.

Comment: `git ls-files` provides possibility of adding an exclusion pattern `--exclude=<pattern>`

Comment: Your example code fails, since `command` is assigned `generate_exclude_dir` but you defined `generate_exclude_dirs()`.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to reproduce the problem. It's a bash escaping problem in the two functions. Try this:

```
generate_exclude_extensions() {
  echo '(cpp$'
}

generate_exclude_dirs() {
  echo '|^test)'
}

command=$(generate_exclude_extensions)$(generate_exclude_dirs)
echo "$command"
git ls-files | grep -vEe "$command"
```

my code to reproduce

```
generate_exclude_extensions() {
  echo '(cpp$'
}

generate_exclude_dirs() {
  echo '|^test)'
}

command=$(generate_exclude_extensions)$(generate_exclude_dirs)
echo "$command"
echo -e 'cpp\n
test\n
test456\n
display?5\n' | grep -vEe "$command"
```

There are also two typos in your script

```
generate_exclude_dir -> generate_exclude_dirs
generate_exclud_extensions -> generate_exclude_extensions
```

:) have fun

Answer (score 1):

Another approach could be:

```
generate_exclude_extensions() {
  echo 'cpp$'
}

generate_exclude_dirs() {
  echo '^test'
}

exclusions=$(
  generate_exclude_extensions
  generate_exclude_dir
)

printf '%s\n' "$exclusions"

git ls-files | grep -ve "$exclusions"
```

That is have one exclusion per line, and then you don't even need `-E`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Git `exclude` [pathspecs](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefpathspecapathspec) to filter the output:

```bsh
exclude_extensions=( '*cpp' '*.txt' ) # added `*.txt` as sample file extension
exclude_dirs=( 'test/*' )             # exclude files in relative directory `test`

git ls-files "${exclude_extensions[@]/#/:(exclude)}" "${exclude_dirs[@]/#/:(exclude)}"
```

The parameter expansion `"${exclude_...[@]/#/:(exclude)}"` expands to the space separated array entries prefixed by `:(`, the pathspec "magic word" `exclude` followed by `)`.

The resulting command is equivalent to

```
git ls-files ':(exclude)*cpp' ':(exclude)*.txt' ':(exclude)test/*'
```